# sql filtering query with number and with declare

Tags: sql, sql-server, declare

I have a question. When I filter on the DOCUMENT_TYPE column, it brings the information very late. About 18-20 seconds.
The number I mentioned in the filter is 2. What is interesting is that when I add this value to the filter in the form of a variable, the data comes in 1 second. What is the reason for this? I need to do this operation without a variable.
The code is below.

```
-- 18-20 second
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[VW_PERFORMANCE_TEST] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (13 = [Extent1].[PERIOD_ID]) AND (2 = [Extent1].[DOCUMENT_TYPE])
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

    

-- 1 second
declare @a int
set @a=2

SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(0) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[VW_PERFORMANCE_TEST] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (13 = [Extent1].[PERIOD_ID]) AND (@a= [Extent1].[DOCUMENT_TYPE])
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: If you switch query order, do you still get the same durations?

Comment: you might have the query plan cached from the previous query so the 2nd runs faster

Comment: yes gives the same second again

Comment: No, I have  used query it on separate pages either

Comment: Compare the execution plans. When you use parameter engine don't know what to expect and will create some neutral plan that's good fit in most situations. When you use hard coded number, engine will create best plan for that situation based on your indexes and statistics. Theoretically that one should be faster, but in your case there are probably some issues with statistics or bad indexing. Perhaps number of rows in table have changed a lot recently. Try dropping and recreating indexes.